# I need to derive a lower frequency clock from the main clock and sample it in verilog

Tags: verilog, counter, sampling, testbench

I have been successful in deriving the clock, but am unable to sample and check the results in the test bench. Attaching the code and the written test bench. Need to find a way to do away with the error->

Line 68: Target  of concurrent assignment or output port connection should be a net type.

The program-

```
module clk_div 
#( 
parameter WIDTH = 4, // Width of the register required
parameter N = 6
)
(clk,reset, clk_out);

input clk;
input reset;
output clk_out;

reg [WIDTH-1:0] reg1;
wire [WIDTH-1:0] next;
reg clk_tmp;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)

begin
  if (reset)
     begin
        reg1 <= 0;
    clk_tmp <= 1'b0;
     end

  else if (next == N)
       begin
         reg1 <= 0;
         clk_tmp <= ~clk_tmp;
       end

  else 
      reg1 <= next;
end

 assign next = reg1+1;            
 assign clk_out = clk_tmp;

endmodule

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module sampling(clk_out, clk, result);
input clk_out;
input clk;
output reg [3:0] result;

clk_div inst (clk_out,rst,result);

reg [3:0] reg2;

always @ (posedge clk_out)
begin
if (clk==1'b1)
reg2[0]<=1;

else
reg2[0]<=0;

reg2<={reg2[2:0], clk_out};
assign result = reg2[0];

end
endmodule
```

It's test bench-

```
module tb1;

    // Inputs
    reg clk_out;
    reg clk;

    // Outputs
    wire [3:0] result;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    sampling uut (
        .clk_out(clk_out), 
        .clk(clk), 
        .result(result)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        clk_out = 0;
        clk = 0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;

        // Add stimulus here
        clk=1'b1;
        forever #10 clk=~clk;

    end

endmodule
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you add a comment in the code pointing out which line is line 68.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably this line:

```
assign result = reg2[0];
```

Because earlier you declared

```
output reg [3:0] result;
```

Nets declared as `reg` type can only be assigned within procedural blocks (`always` and `initial` blocks).

If you want to use continuous assignment, you must declare the variable as a wire type.

In the case of an output, that just means removing the `reg` keyword from the declaration:

```
output [3:0] result;
```

Comment: Thanks The Photon!

I did as you said.. now it gives me the following error->

Line 81: Procedural assignment to a non-register result is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar

Line 81 here is->

assign result = reg2[0];

Comment: @Ameya, your `assign` statement should not be inside any `always` block.